# Mathematical expression exceed the cell

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, tabularray

I would like to fix the table in which each cell contains the whole mathematical expression inside the cell, not exceed it. The following code produces this

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
%\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, mathtools, amsfonts, mathrsfs, mathtools,}
\usepackage[showframe,a4paper,margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
%\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{43pt}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Measure theory} \\
        \hline
$\mathcal{C}\subset \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ est un \textbf{Clan} sur $\Omega$ 
& $\mathcal{A}\subset \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ est une \textbf{Algébre de Boole} sur $\Omega$
&$\mathcal{F}\subset \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ est une \textbf{Tribu} ou $\sigma$-\textbf{algébre} sur $\Omega$ \\
        \hline
Cell 1 & Cell 2 & Cell 3 \\
                \hline
\boxed{$\begin{cases}
 A\in \mathcal{C} \implies A^{c}\in\mathcal{C} &\\
  A,B\in \mathcal{C} \implies A\cup B\in\mathcal{C} &\\
    \end{cases}$}
& 
\boxed{$\begin{cases}
    \emptyset \in \mathcal{A} &\\
    A\in \mathcal{A} \implies A^{c}\in\mathcal{A} &\\
    A,B\in \mathcal{A} \implies A\cup B\in\mathcal{A} &\\
\end{cases}$}
& 
\boxed{$\begin{cases}
        \emptyset \in \mathcal{A} &\\
        A\in \mathcal{A} \implies A^{c}\in\mathcal{A} &\\
        \{A_{n},\;n\in\mathbb{N} \}\subset \mathcal{F}\implies \bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_{n}\in\mathcal{F}&\\
    \end{cases}$}
\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your narrow columns (3cm) with the large `\tabcolsep` cause the boxed equations not to fit. So change this. And then, your code doesn't compile because `\boxed` puts its contents in math mode, so you shouldn't use `$` inside it.

Comment: I tried to do so with no luck

Comment: Can you please add the real contents of the second row?

Comment: The second row will also contain complex mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

- Used is `tabularray`  package
- In table is used `\small` font size
- Macro `boxed` is moved in math environments

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, mathtools, mathrsfs,}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\small
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {X[0.9,c] X[0.9c] X[c] },
                 row{1} = {mode=text},
                 colsep = {4pt},
                 rowsep = {5pt}
                }
\SetCell[c=3]{c}    Measure theory          \\
%
{$\mathcal{C}\subset\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ est un\\ 
  \textbf{Clan} sur $\Omega$}
    &   {$\mathcal{A}\subset \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ est une\\ 
          \textbf{Algébre de Boole} sur $\Omega$}
    &   {$\mathcal{F}\subset \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ est une\\
          \textbf{Tribu} ou $\sigma$-\textbf{algébre} sur $\Omega$} \\
Cell 1  & Cell 2    & Cell 3    \\
$\boxed{\left\{\begin{array}{r@{\,}l}
 A\in   \mathcal{C} & \implies A^{c}\in\mathcal{C}          \\
 A,B\in \mathcal{C} & \implies A\cup B\in\mathcal{C}        \\
 \end{array}\right.}$
    &   $\boxed{\left\{\begin{array}{r@{\,}l}
    \emptyset & \in \mathcal{A}  \\
    A   & \in \mathcal{A}\implies A^{c}\in\mathcal{A}      \\
    A,B & \in \mathcal{A}\implies A\cup B\in\mathcal{A}    \\
         \end{array}\right.}$ 
        &   $\boxed{\left\{\begin{array}{r@{\,}l}
        \emptyset & \in \mathcal{A}\\
        A         & \in \mathcal{A} \implies A^{c}\in\mathcal{A}  \\
        \left\{\begin{gathered}
            A_{n},\\
            n\in\mathbb{N} 
            \end{gathered}\right\}
                  & \subset \mathcal{F} \implies \bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_{n}\in\mathcal{F}
            \end{array}\right.}$      \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```